# MVC3 post multiple forms together in one action

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have two forms in my view:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("EditProject", "Projects", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "project_edit_form" }))
    {  
         @Html.Partial("_ProjectPartial", Model.Project })
    }
...other
    @using (Html.BeginForm("EditProject", "Projects", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "sub_project_edit_form" }))
    {    
         @Html.Partial("_SubProjectsPartial", Model.SubProjects)
    }
```

I want post these two forms together.

I post these forms by next javascript:

```
$('#project_edit_form, #sub_project_edit_form').submit();
```

I catch this form like this:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult EditProject(Project project, List<SubProjects> subProjects)
        {}
```

After that, I have not null project, but fields of project not mapped, subProjects are maped  right. If i post project and subprojects from one form, all works fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are u using two forms when u can use single form and submit with whatever model or data u want?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can have more than one `form` element on the web page but you **cannot** nest them.

You can read this in [W3C html specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html)

> 4.10.3 The form element
>
> Content model:
>
> Flow content, but with no form element descendants.

Comment: My forms are not nested. It just is two different forms on one page.

Comment: @oschepkov Sorry, bad formatting in your code. One question: you submit only one form?

Comment: No, i try to submit both forms together. If i put my partialviews in one form all works fine. I have one button for submit.

Comment: How you can post two forms together? Each one has it own address which you send GET/POST